# Iterating through TableLayoutPanel to dispose controls - some controls get skipped

Tags: c#, foreach, dispose, tablelayoutpanel

I have a dynamically created `TableLayoutPanel`, in which each cell (except those in the first row) contains a control that is added during runtime (two of them with `EventHandlers`).  I need be able to clear out the contents of that table, so I wrote a method for this purpose:

```
private void clearDataLogs()
{
    tableLayoutPanel_dataLogs.Visible = false;
    button_saveSelectedLogs.Visible = false;
    tableLayoutPanel_dataLogs.SuspendLayout();
    int loopCount = 0;
    TableLayoutControlCollection controls = tableLayoutPanel_dataLogs.Controls;
    foreach (Control control in controls)
    {
        var count = controls.Count;
        loopCount++;
        int row = tableLayoutPanel_dataLogs.GetCellPosition(control).Row;
        if (row != 0)
        {
            if (control.Name.Contains(ControlNames.checkBoxSelectedName)) ((CheckBox)control).CheckedChanged -= new System.EventHandler(this.checkBox_getAnyDataLog_CheckedChanged);
            else if (control.Name.Contains(ControlNames.textBoxFileNameName)) ((TextBox)control).TextChanged -= new System.EventHandler(this.textBoxFileName_TextChanged);
            tableLayoutPanel_dataLogs.Controls.Remove(control);
            control.Dispose();
        }
    }

    while (tableLayoutPanel_dataLogs.RowCount > 1)
    {
        int row = tableLayoutPanel_dataLogs.RowCount - 1;
        tableLayoutPanel_dataLogs.RowStyles.RemoveAt(row);
        tableLayoutPanel_dataLogs.RowCount--;
    }
    tableLayoutPanel_dataLogs.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(530, 56);
    tableLayoutPanel_dataLogs.AutoScroll = true;
    tableLayoutPanel_dataLogs.Visible = false;
    tableLayoutPanel_dataLogs.ResumeLayout();
    tableLayoutPanel_dataLogs.PerformLayout();
}
```

The code should iterate through every control in the panel, removing the controls in each row except the first row.  I even added checks to get rid of the handlers for the controls that will have them.

The problem is this: when I run the code, it never seems to get all the controls.  The `count` and `loopCount` variables in there are just for debugging.  In the simplest case, `count` is 14, but `loopCount` gets to 9 or 10 at the end of the loop.  This is the most vexing part: *the controls that get skipped are not always the same each time I run the method!!!*

What is going on with this, and how might I fix it?

Comment: you are iterating on the same thing you are removing from.  use a for n loop and go backwards

Comment: OK, changed the foreach to `for (int i = controls.Count - 1; i > 0; i--)` and added the oh-so-important line `Control control = controls[i];` which now allows me to remove and dispose.  Works fine now.  Thanks!